# How can I filter by two columns in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Given this [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP96GwK2_rBGYjMYnp37OWIRqTHPSxIrqlL-8eiLRyY/edit#gid=0) and these two pairs, how can I filter that table (from the UI) so I cann see the full rows of these two?

I have tried to fill in the `filter by condition`->`custom formula`->

`=QUERY(A:B; "where A='2021-01-25' and B='domain3'"; 0)`

`=QUERY(A:B; "where A='2021-01-27' and B='domain1'"; 0)`

but it hasn't returned any results, plus I want to get 2 pairs.

1. Is this the way to use formula in the `filter by condition` ?
2. I can use apps script if it simplifies.

[image]

Comment: @player0 maybe you would know

Comment: Why the tags google-apps script and google-sheets-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the dates in column A to plain text and then use this formula:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select * where (A='2021-01-25' and B = 'domain3') or (A='2021-01-27' and B = 'domain1') ")
```

**Join multiple tables:**

```
=QUERY({A:B;G:H}, "select * where (Col1='2021-01-25' and Col2 = 'domain1') or (Col1='2021-01-26' and Col2 = 'domain2') order by Col1 ")
```

[image]

Comment: But how will I get 2 pairs? `<date1, domain1>` and `<date2, domain3>`?

Comment: Thanks, can I do it from the filter data ui menu? as seen in my screenshot?

Comment: @EladBenda thats not possible because if you filter on two columns it will give you all the results and not the exact pairs.

Comment: say I have these pairs in another 2 column table in the sheet. How can I automatically create your formula? Meaning i kind of want to join the two tables. See my new screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWP5R.png

Comment: @EladBenda I updated my answer. You can omit the `order by Col1` if you don't want to sort them.